# Drop element in numpy array (or pandas series) if difference to previous element is <N

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, filter, selection

I have a numpy array that looks like that:

`a = np.array([0,10,19,20,30,40,42,49,50,51])`

I would like to drop all the elements whose consecutive difference is <= 2, eventually keeping

`a_filtered = np.array([0,10,19,30,40,49])`

How can I do this in numpy? Optionally, special thanks for how to do this in a pandas series (e.g. drop all rows whose index difference is < N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
s=pd.Series(a)
s[~(s.diff()<=2)]
Out[289]: 
0     0
1    10
2    19
4    30
5    40
7    49
dtype: int32
```

---

```
s[~(s.diff()<=2)].to_numpy()
Out[292]: array([ 0, 10, 19, 30, 40, 49])
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I see that I can't perform this on the index of the dataframe, means it doesn't work for `s=df.index`. Do you have a solution for that? And how would it work if `s` would be a numpy array?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
N = 2
s = pd.Series(a)

mask = ~s.diff().le(2)
s[mask]

# you can also do
# a[mask]
```

Output:

```
1    10
2    19
4    30
5    40
7    49
dtype: int32
```

Comment: 0 is missing  :-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen ouch. I'll stole your idea then :-)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I see that I can't perform this on the index of the data frame, means it doesn't work for `s=df.index`. Do you have a solution for that? And how would it work if `s` would be a numpy array?

Comment: `s=df.index.to_series()` or `s=df.index.values`.

Comment: And if `s` is numpy array?

Answer (score 1):

On numpy, you may use `np.diff` and `np.insert` to specially handle element `0`

```
m = np.insert(np.diff(a, 1) > 2, 0, True)
a[m]

Out[526]: array([ 0, 10, 19, 30, 40, 49])
```

---

Or Use `np.roll` and assign element `0` of the mask to `True`

```
m = (a - np.roll(a, 1)) > 2
m[0] = True
a[m]

Out[534]: array([ 0, 10, 19, 30, 40, 49])
```